# How to check if an Array is an Array of empty Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

In my `node.js 6.10` app, I am trying to identify in my array looks like this:

```
[
    [
        []
    ],
    []
]
```

This nesting can go onto n level, and can have elements in arrays at any level. How can I do this? Thanks

**P.S.** I know I can do it using a n level for loop, but was wondering about a more optimized solution.

Comment: Create a recursive function, maybe?

Comment: `arr.toString().replace(/,/g,'')  === true`

Comment: ^^^ This will fail if the array is full strings of commas

Comment: `arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '') === '';`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An one-liner:

```js
let isEmpty = a => Array.isArray(a) && a.every(isEmpty);

//

let zz = [
    [
        []
    ],
    [],
    [[[[[[]]]]]]
]


console.log(isEmpty(zz))
```

If you're wondering how this works, remember that any statement about an empty set is true ("[vacuous truth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)), therefore `a.every(isEmpty)` is true for both empty arrays and arrays that contain only empty arrays.

Comment: Even simpler to use lodash :)

Comment: I think trying to do something any better than this is just waste of time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const arr = [[[]],[]]
const isEmpty = a => a.toString().replace(/,/g, '') === ''

console.log(isEmpty(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

All you need is to write recursive function, that checks `array.length` property on its way.

Something like that:

```
function isEmpty(arr) {
let result = true;

for (let el of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
        result = isEmpty(el); 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

return result;
```

}

You may consider to use lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/#flattenDeep

Answer (score -1):

Another compact solution that utilises [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
[].concat.apply([], [[], [], []]).length; // 0
```

Comment: It won't work in case of nested arrays, like: `[[], [], [[]]]`